# getting negative values for tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, softmax

I am using TensorFlow to get classes for individual pixels using convolution/deconvolution, similar to the architecture described in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.04366.pdf. However, my `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, labels)` function is returning very high negative values. There are only two classes that I am working with, so labels have an entry of either 0 or 1. Is there a problem with my architecture? This is the code I am running -

```
def new_weights(shape):
return tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape, mean = 1, stddev=0.05))

def new_biases(length):
    return tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.05, shape=[length]))

def new_conv_layer(input,num_input_channels,filter_size,num_filters,use_pooling=True):
    shape = [filter_size, filter_size, num_input_channels, num_filters]
    weights = new_weights(shape=shape)
    biases = new_biases(length=num_filters)
    layer = tf.nn.conv2d(input=input,
                         filter=weights,
                         strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                         padding='SAME')
    layer += biases
    if use_pooling:
        layer = tf.nn.max_pool(value=layer,
                               ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                               strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                               padding='SAME')
    layer = tf.nn.relu(layer)
    return layer, weights

def new_deconv_layer(input, num_input_channels, filter_size, num_filters, output_shape, resize_width, use_unpooling=True):
    shape = [filter_size, filter_size, num_filters, num_input_channels]
    weights = new_weights(shape=shape)
    biases = new_biases(length=num_filters)
    layer = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(value=input,filter=weights,output_shape=output_shape,strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],padding='SAME')
    layer += biases
    if use_unpooling:
        layer = tf.image.resize_images(layer, size = [resize_width, resize_width], method=tf.image.ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR)
    layer = tf.nn.relu(layer)
    return layer, weights
```

This is my architecture -

```
batch_size = 164
img_size = 128
img_size_flat = img_size * img_size
img_shape = (img_size, img_size)
num_channels = 3
num_classes = 2
filter_size1 = 5 
num_filters1 = 16
filter_size2 = 5 
num_filters2 = 32
filter_size3 = 5 
num_filters3 = 36
num_filters5 = 36
filter_size5 = 5
num_filters6 = 32
filter_size6 = 5
num_filters7 = 16
filter_size7 = 5
num_filters8 = 2
filter_size8 = 5


layer_conv1, weights_conv1 = new_conv_layer(input=inputs, num_input_channels=num_channels, filter_size=filter_size1, num_filters=num_filters1, use_pooling=True)

layer_conv2, weights_conv2 = new_conv_layer(input=layer_conv1, num_input_channels=num_filters1, filter_size=filter_size2, num_filters=num_filters2, use_pooling=True)

layer_conv3, weights_conv3 = new_conv_layer(input=layer_conv2, num_input_channels=num_filters2, filter_size=filter_size3, num_filters=num_filters3, use_pooling=True)

layer_deconv5, weights_deconv5 = new_deconv_layer(input=layer_conv3, num_input_channels=num_filters5, filter_size=filter_size5, num_filters=num_filters5, output_shape=[batch_size,16,16,36], resize_width=32, use_unpooling=True)

layer_deconv6, weights_deconv6 = new_deconv_layer(input=layer_deconv5, num_input_channels=num_filters5, filter_size=filter_size6, num_filters=num_filters6, output_shape=[batch_size,32,32,32], resize_width=64, use_unpooling=True)

layer_deconv7, weights_deconv7 = new_deconv_layer(input=layer_deconv6, num_input_channels=num_filters6, filter_size=filter_size7, num_filters=num_filters7, output_shape=[batch_size,64,64,16], resize_width=128, use_unpooling=True)

layer_deconv8, weights_deconv8 = new_deconv_layer(input=layer_deconv7, num_input_channels=num_filters7, filter_size=filter_size8, num_filters=num_filters8, output_shape=[batch_size,128,128,2], resize_width=128, use_unpooling=False)

loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=layer_deconv8, labels=labels)

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-4).minimize(loss)
```

I am new to TensorFlow, so any help will be appreciated. Thank you so much!

Edit - The exact error message is `Invalid argument: Received a label value of -9191425209310543503 which is outside the valid range of [0, 2)`

Edit 2 - Basically, I have the black and white masks of the images also, in addition to the RGB images. If the pixel value of the mask is not 0, it belongs in class 1, else it belongs to the background (class 0). The code is as follows -

```
for i in range(batch_size):
    for j in range(128):
        for k in range(128):
            if y_true[i][j][k] != 0:
                labels[i][j][k] = 1
```

Comment: how do you know it returns negative values, did you print it?

Comment: @AliAbbasi check the edit above

Comment: The error says that, you must assign 0 or 1 to your labels but you assign `-9191425209310543503`, it seems you have the problem with your true labels, it is not about the output of sparse_softmax, can you show the codes where you define labels

Comment: @AliAbbasi yeah, I've added another edit. Thanks for your help!

Comment: how do you define `labels[i][j][k]`, is it numpy?

Comment: @AliAbbasi oh, I resolved this. It was a trivial error, I had not initialised labels[i][j][k] in case y_true[i][j][k] == 0. Hence these were uninitialised values. However, there is something off with this model. It takes 40 seconds to compute 164 images! And I have horrible specs (I am running this on a virtual machine)

Comment: The complete code is on https://gist.github.com/avyavkumar/bd03119d4decd6e810e3835dee465bd3